# How to understand the limus test #5 in "A formal kernel memory-ordering model"?

Tags: linux, riscv, memory-barriers, memory-model

In the article "[A formal kernel memory-ordering model](https://lwn.net/Articles/720550/)", the following counterintuitive memory model litmus test is presented:

```
P0(int *a, int *b)
{
  WRITE_ONCE(*a, 1);    //1
  smp_wmb();
  WRITE_ONCE(*b, 1);    //2
}

P1(int *a, int *b)
{
  int r1;

  WRITE_ONCE(*b, 2);    //3
  smp_mb();
  r1 = READ_ONCE(*a);   //4
}

exists
(b=2 /\ 1:r1=0)
```

The observation `b == 2` implies that 3) completed after 2). And since 2) is ordered after 1), the observation `r1 == 0` should never be possible. The given explanation is that an observation of `b == 2` does not imply 3) was ordered after 2). Instead it is possible that a memory write that is issued earlier by one hart to overwrite a memory write issued later by another hart. Page 71-72 of [this presentation](http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/LinuxMM.2017.01.19a-ext.LCA.pdf) shows one mechanism by which this can happen.

Does this really happen in current hardware? RISC-V, for example, has the following "Load Value Axiom" in its [specification](https://riscv.org/specifications/) (page 88):

> Each byte of each load *i* returns the value written to that byte by the store that is the latest in global memory order among the following stores:
>
> 1. Stores that write that byte and that precede *i* in the global memory order
> 2. Stores that write that byte and that precede *i* in program order

Does this forbid the observation that an earlier write can overwrite a later one?

Comment: Is "hart" a mis-translation for "core", as in CPU core?

Comment: "hart" is short for "hardware thread"

Comment: Ok, apparently that term was made up for RISC-V.  [RiscV spec references the word 'hart' - what does 'hart' mean?](//stackoverflow.com/q/42676827).  I've never seen it used in any other computer-architecture discussion.  I guess it would be useful to have a short word that means "logical core".

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of reading, here is my current understanding of the problem.

Unlike the RVWMO model of RISC-V, the strong model of Linux kernel contains the concept of "write propagation". The strong model definition states that: (emphasis mine)

> When a CPU submits a read request for a specified target address, the
>   memory subsystem finds the latest write (in the target address's
>   coherence order) **that has propagated to the CPU** and returns the value
>   stored by that write.

This stands in contrast to the load value axiom of RVWMO, whose memory simply returns the latest write in global memory order. In other words, RVWMO assumes that each memory write propagates to all CPUs immediately and simultaneously.

Correspondingly, there is a significant difference between `smp_wmb()` and `smp_mb()`. The `smp_wmb()` is a weak barrier, while `smp_mb()` is a strong barrier. A weak barrier simply tells the memory that writes after the barrier should always be propagated after all writes before the barrier. A strong barrier will actually wait until previous writes have been propagated to all CPUs and the "coherence point".

So here's my idea of what's going on during the litmus test:

1. P0 sends the two writes and the barrier to the memory. They then propagated to the coherence point, but did not reach P1.
2. P1 sends the write to the memory and waits until it propagated to P0. During this period neither write from P0 reached P1. Because the write from P1 reaches the coherence point later than that from P0, the final value of `b` is `2`.
3. P1 reads the variable `a`. Because the write from P0 has not reached P1 yet, it gets the initial value `0`.
4. The writes from P0 finally reaches P1. However, P1 never sees `b == 1`, since `WRITE_ONCE(*b, 2);` comes later in coherence order.

Now why does replacing `smp_wmb()` with `smp_mb()` eliminates the observed result? Because in this case P0 will actually wait until its first write has propagated to P1, before sending its second write. Now `r1 == 0` implies that the barrier in P0 is still unfinished, but the barrier in P1 ensures that the write in P1 has reached all CPUs and the coherence point. Therefore the second write in P0 must reach the coherence point later than the write in P1. Hence we cannot have `b == 2`.

Comment: A memory model where some cores can see a store before it becomes globally visible is a *weakly*-ordered model, not strong.  For example, POWER has this property.  (aka it's not multi-copy-atomic).  See [Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](//stackoverflow.com/a/50679223) for a C++11 `std::atomic` question, with an answer about how IRIW reordering can happen in practice on some POWER hardware.  (Not the same as your litmus test, but one where write propagation matters, and where acq/rel is weaker than seq_cst)

Comment: The "strong model" here is a terminology specific to Linux kernel. It contrasts with a "weak model" which removes certain constraints. See: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/LWNLinuxMM/WeakModel.html